# Git: 1.List all files in a branch, 2.compare files from different branch

Tags: git

1. Looking for a command like `ls -R` or `dir/s` that can list all files in a commit/branch.
2. Is there any command that can compare two files from different branches?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

1. `git ls-tree -r --name-only <commit>` (where instead of `<commit>` there can be `<branch>`).
     You might want to use also `-t` option which lists subdirectories before descending into them
2. `git diff <branchA>:<fileA> <branchB>:<fileB>`,
    or if you want to compare the same file `git diff <branchA> <branchB> -- <file>`

Comment: If you want to list a specific directory you can add a colon followed by the path to the branch ie:
git ls-tree -r --name-only master:directory/path/name

Comment: git ls-tree... <branch> seems to list all files in the repo not just those in the branch?

Comment: It seems like `-r` and `--name-only` no longer exist for `git ls-files`. Does anyone know if their syntax was replaced with something equivalent? I'm not seeing anything obvious while scanning over the manual. I believe this answer should be updated to specify that either it is no longer possible or else what the new equivalent is. (Speaking from Git 2.41.0 on Gentoo.)

Comment: @cryptarch **`git ls-files`** and `git ls-tree` are different commands. By default `git ls-files` is recursive (`-r` for `git ls-tree`) and shows only file names (`--name-only` for `git ls-tree`), unless you are using `git ls-files` with options for showing the staging area, etc. `git ls-files` shows what is in working area, `git ls-tree` shows what's in git repository (what's in the **commit** or **branch**).

Comment: @JakubNarębski Ah, I completely misread. Sorry for the noise! and thanks for being patient with me :)

Answer (score 37):

To compare the same file from different branches:

```
git diff branch_1..branch_2 file.txt
```

To list all files in a tree object:

```
git ls-tree -r branch
```

Comment: I get "git: 'ls' is not a git command. See 'git --help'." and I'm using git v 2.19.0.

Comment: It's not just `ls`, you've forgotten the `-tree` on the end :)

Comment: Ah I assumed is was ls -tree. I thought -tree was a switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

To list all files added in the new branch

```
git diff --name-only branch1 master
```

Comment: This lists only the names of all files that have changed, not just the new files.

Answer (score 6):

## List files in branch with  `git ls-files`

1. Try `git ls-files` described in the [git-scm docu](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files):

```sh
# Switch to <branch> of interest
$ git checkout <branch>
# List all files in <branch>
$ git ls-files
```

For further options check the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Comment: YES - THATS WHAT I WANTED!!

Answer (score 3):

### As of Git v2.1.0 [08/15/14]

For listing, you may use `git ls-files` to list all files recursively in the current index/working directory. You may refer to [Git-SCM Docs / git-ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) or type `man git-ls-files` if you have installed Git and have man pages available.

It has nice options to show files in different ways like `cached`, `staged`, `deleted`, `modified`, `ignored` or `others` for the untracked. It also supports matching patterns. Having also a `--debug` arg, you can easily list `creation time`, `modification time`, `inode id`, `owner & group id`, `size` and `flags` for files.

---

For the diff of two branch, simply use `git diff <branch> <other branch>` as stated in other answers.