# How can I only get the folder names of the current working branch in GitHub Actions?

Tags: bash, git, github, github-actions

I have a workflow and one of its steps is to search for all existing folders on the current branch (not Main or Master).

However, I got all directories including those that only exist in the master branch when doing `echo $(git ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD)`.

Do I miss anything?

Complete code snippet:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:
    fetch-depth: 2
- name: current folders
  run: |
    echo $(git ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD)
```

Comment: Why do you `echo $(...)` instead of simply `...`?

Comment: For demonstration, I don't do echo in the actual code either.

Comment: _"including those that only exist in the master branch"_ - No, `git ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD` only lists those directories seen on the current branch. If a directory is not present on the current branch, it will not be listed.

Comment: If your action is running from main/master, you can use `git ls-tree [options] [branch]` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1910822/5774952). If you want the action to actually run on a different branch, you can do that with a [ref in your workflow](https://github.com/actions/checkout#Checkout-a-different-branch)

Comment: @ZacAnger It says _"current branch"_ in the question

Comment: Actually I think I miss a point: I ran `echo $(git ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD)` on the local machine and it works as I expected, but not on Github Actions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo whoops, you're right, my mind is muddled.

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem by merging the master branch to the current one.